# How to Move a cell contents using VBA

Tags: vba, move

I’m trying to develop a small program using VBA and would like to add to it. As always I’m struggling to get it right any really could use some help on this project. I not sure how does the program move contents down from one cell to the next if the next cell is full without overwriting it and then move that one down.
I hope you can help.

I'm currently using the program below.

```
Sub do_it()

    Dim n, sht As Worksheet, cell As Range, num, tmp, rngDest As Range

    Set sht = ActiveSheet

    n = sht.Range("A1")

    For Each cell In sht.Range("D1:D12,A16:A31,D16:D31,G16:G31,J16:J31,M16:M31").Cells

        tmp = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value

        If cell.Value = n And tmp Like "*#-#*" Then

            'get the first number
            num = CLng(Trim(Split(tmp, "-")(0)))
            Debug.Print "Found a positive result in " & cell.Address

            'find the next empty cell in the appropriate row
            Set rngDest = sht.Cells(num, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)
            'make sure not to add before col L
            If rngDest.Column < 12 Then Set rngDest = sht.Cells(num, 12)

            cell.Offset(0, 1).Copy rngDest
            Exit For

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

I'm trying to have the program move all the number sets down in the column in the 6 column ranges E1:E12,B16:B30,E16:E30,H16:H30,K16:K30,N16:N30.

In only column E1:E12 I need the program to move the set of numbers (could be more than one set of numbers in the range) down to the following cell below it and increase the last number in the set (no limit to the count). So in the example of cell E1 (8-16)  would move to E2 and become 8-17 (cell E1 would be blank when after the move). 
When sets of number are located in cell E12 they would move to E1 but still increase the last number and would go round and round. Need help on the next one, how does the program move contents down from one cell to the next if the next cell is full without overwriting it and then move that one down, if this makes sense. An example is cell E12, how does it move up to E1 if E1 is full but has to be moved, which goes first?

For the remaining column ranges B16:B30,E16:E30,H16:H30,K16:K30,N16:N30 I need the program to move the set of numbers (could be more than one set of numbers in the range) down to the following cell below it and increase the last number in the set (no limit to the count). So in the example of cell N18 (5-3) it would move it to N19 and become 5-4 (delete the contents in N18 when finished). The second adjacent column to the right of the above, N18 in this case and located in only the following locations: C16:C30,F16:F30,I16:I30,L16:L30,O16:O30 have cells that contain values that must move but with no change in number. Cell O18 would move down to O19 and still have the number of 9.99. After the operation N18 and O18 would then be blank).

The two exceptions are if the last number is a 15, see cell B30 (8-15).  Two things must happen:

1) I need the program to reference the number in the following 5 possible cells:

```
Cell B30 go to cell B32, reference number 1
Cell E30 go to cell E32, reference number 2
Cell H30 go to cell H32, reference number 3
Cell K30 go to cell K32, reference number 4
Cell N30 go to cell N32, reference number 5
```

Using example B30 the reference number is 1 (B32) so the program would search the range in column D1:D12 for the number 1 and move the set of numbers and increase the last digit, so it would become 8-16 in cell number E1.

2) The value in cell C31 must be moved via referencing the first number in cell B30 as a reference and search the following 10 possible cells: A35,D35,G35,J35,M35,Q35,A39,D39G39,J39,M39,O39 to find that number (in this example 8 would be cell D39 and the number 2.22 would be moved to cell D40.

After this operation there is no contents in either cell B30 and C30.

That’s it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gySQK.jpg)

Comment: **TLDR** **TLDR**

Comment: You have wayyyy to much info here. Also, you are telling us that cell `K1` is in row 1 which is completely not necessary. Please [edit] your question down. Explain 1 specific problem, what you have tried, and state a actual question. Not that "Can you help me" is not a question :) *Good luck*

Comment: I have have fixed my request, thanks Russ

Answer (score 0):

> I not sure how does the program move contents down from one cell to the next if the next cell is full without overwriting it and then move that one down.

This should help with that:

```
  Cells(irow + 1, icol).Insert Shift:=xlDown
  Cells(irow, icol).Copy Cells(irow + 1, icol)
  Cells(irow, icol).Clear
```

Comment: Thank-you dcromley I will definitely try it out.

Comment: Hi, I tried your code but I can't get it to work so I have posted the program to see if can spot the issue.                 

Sub do_it()

    Dim n, sht As Worksheet, cell As Range, num, tmp, rngDest As Range

    Set sht = ActiveSheet

    n = sht.Range("A1")

    For Each cell In sht.Range("D1:D12,A16:A30,D16:D30,G16:G30,J16:J30,M16:M30").Cells

        tmp = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value

        If cell.Value = n And tmp Like "*#-#*" Then

            'get the first number
            num = CLng(Trim(Split(tmp, "-")(0)))
            Debug.Print "Found a positive result in